# GCP Cloud Tasks: shorten period for creating a previously created named task

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

We are developing a GCP Cloud Task based queue process that sends a status email whenever a particular Firestore doc write-trigger fires. The reason we use Cloud Tasks is so a delay can be created (using scheduledTime property 2-min in the future) before the email is sent, and to control dedup (by using a task-name formatted as: [firestore-collection-name]-[doc-id]) since the 'write' trigger on the Firestore doc can be fired several times as the document is being created and then quickly updated by backend cloud functions.

Once the task's delay period has been reached, the cloud-task runs, and the email is sent with updated Firestore document info included. After which the task is deleted from the queue and all is good.

Except:

If the user updates the Firestore doc (say 20 or 30 min later) we want to resend the status email but are unable to create the task using the same task-name. We get the following error:

```
409 The task cannot be created because a task with this name existed too recently. For more information about task de-duplication see https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks/create#body.request_body.FIELDS.task.
```

This was unexpected as the queue is empty at this point as the last task completed succesfully. The documentation referenced in the error message says:

> If the task's queue was created using Cloud Tasks, then another task
> with the same name can't be created for ~1hour after the original task
> was deleted or executed.

Question: is there some way in which this restriction can be by-passed by lowering the amount of time, or even removing the restriction all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is No. As you've already pointed, the docs are very clear regarding this behavior and you should wait 1 hour to create a task with same name as one that was previously created. The API or Client Libraries does not allow to decrease this time.

Having said that, I would suggest that instead of using the same Task ID, use different ones for the task and add an identifier in the body of the request. For example, using Python:

```py
from google.cloud import tasks_v2
from google.protobuf import timestamp_pb2
import datetime

def create_task(project, queue, location, payload=None, in_seconds=None):
    client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()

    parent = client.queue_path(project, location, queue)

    task = {
            'app_engine_http_request': {
                'http_method': 'POST',
                'relative_uri': '/task/'+queue
            }
    }
    if payload is not None:
        converted_payload = payload.encode()

        task['app_engine_http_request']['body'] = converted_payload

    if in_seconds is not None:
        d = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=in_seconds)

        timestamp = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
        timestamp.FromDatetime(d)

        task['schedule_time'] = timestamp

    response = client.create_task(parent, task)

    print('Created task {}'.format(response.name))
    print(response)

#You can change DOCUMENT_ID with USER_ID or something to identify the task
create_task(PROJECT_ID, QUEUE, REGION, DOCUMENT_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In our case however our primary business need is to avoid sending multiple emails that might result from the Firestore doc being updated independently by Cloud Functions firing off the write trigger. We had hoped that Cloud Tasks would allow us to postpone sending an email while at the same time deduping the queue by using a named task based on doc id. Putting the doc id (or whatever) in the payload doesn't solve our deduping need if we are using a unique task name every time. 

Marking yours as answer since you are confirming the restriction.

Comment: @Gatmando Did you find any work around without compromising the inbuilt de-duplication . I too facing this same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69587915/google-cloud-tasks-not-getting-created-from-cloud-functions-error-status-not

Comment: Not really :/ and the reason is that this condition is checked inside Cloud Tasks rather than something we can configure. Maybe Pub/Sub can be another alternative if it works for you

Comment: Cant use pubsub. We are in need of a delayed execution.  We also require deduplication. Our scenario is like , for 10 new Firestore insertion that happens within a millisecond, we need to create only one task to process all the 10 . Task name is based on the parent collection id

Comment: @Oooha. No we didn't find a work around. Because of time constraints we ended up creating our own custom queue using Firestore which is a horrible way to do it but works for now. Its been over a year and I've been meaning to dig into this issue to see if anything has changed in GCP's Cloud Tasks service that might now allow this. I'll update if I find something new.

Comment: Has anyone experienced a case where the task is still not being created even after 1 hour has passed since the previous task with the same ID was deleted or executed? I am experiencing this issue.. The task was created using Client Library.

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar problem of requiring to debounce multiple instances of Firestore write-trigger functions, we worked around the default Cloud Tasks task-name based dedup mechanism (still a constraint in Nov 2022) by building a small debounce "helper" using Firestore transactions.

We're using a helper collection `_syncHelper_` to implement a delayed throttle for side effects of write-trigger fires - in the OP's case, send 1 email for all writes within 2 minutes.

In our case we are using Firebease Functions task queue utils and not directly interacting with Cloud Tasks but thats immaterial to the solution. The key is to determine the task's execution time in advance and use that as the "dedup key":

```
async function enqueueTask(shopId) {
    const queueName = 'doSomething';
    const now =  new Date();
    const next = new Date(now.getTime() + 2 * 60 * 1000);
    try {
        const shouldEnqueue = await getFirestore().runTransaction(async t=>{
            const syncRef = getFirestore().collection('_syncHelper_').doc(<collection_id-doc_id>);
            const doc = await t.get(syncRef);
            let data = doc.data();
            if (data?.timestamp.toDate()> now) {                    
                return false;
            }
            await t.set(syncRef, { timestamp: Timestamp.fromDate(next) });
            return true;
        });
        if (shouldEnqueue) {
            let queue = getFunctions().taskQueue(queueName);
            await queue.enqueue({
                timestamp: next.toISOString(),
            },
                { scheduleTime: next });            }
    }  catch {
        ...
    }
}
```

This will ensure a new task is enqueued only if the "next execution" time has passed.

The execution operation (also a cloud function in our case) will remove the sync data entry if it hasn't been changed since it was executed:

```
exports.doSomething = functions.tasks.taskQueue({
    retryConfig: {
        maxAttempts: 2,
        minBackoffSeconds: 60,
    },
    rateLimits: {
        maxConcurrentDispatches: 2,
    }
}).onDispatch(async data => {
    let { timestamp } = data;
    await sendYourEmailHere();

    await getFirestore().runTransaction(async t => {
        const syncRef = getFirestore().collection('_syncHelper_').doc(<collection_id-doc_id>);
        const doc = await t.get(syncRef);
        let data = doc.data();
        if (data?.timestamp.toDate() <= new Date(timestamp)) {
            await t.delete(syncRef);
        }
    });
});
```

This isn't a bullet proof solution (if the `doSomething()` execution function has high latency for example) but good enough for 99% of our use cases.