# Cloud Tasks - waiting for a result

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

My application needs front-end searching. It searches an external API, for which I'm limited to a few calls per second.

So, I wanted to keep ALL queries, related to this external API, on the same Cloud Task queue, so I could guarantee the amount of calls per second.

That means the user would have to wait for second or two, most likely, when searching.

However, using Google's `const { CloudTasksClient } = require('@google-cloud/tasks')` library, I can create a task but when I go to check it's status using `.getTask()` it says:

```
The task no longer exists, though a task with this name existed recently.
```

Is there any way to poll a task until it's complete and retrieve response data? Or any other recommended methods for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may have a look at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69587915/google-cloud-tasks-not-getting-created-error-status-409-the-task-cannot-be-cr) link once

Comment: Cloud Task is a Async service. You can't wait for something. You have to implement that rate limit in your code or build a more complex thing on top of that.

Comment: @GouravB This wasn't a helpful answer and isn't a helpful comment, now that you've deleted your answer. My question is "Is there any way to poll a task until it's complete and retrieve response data?" not, "is this expected behaviour?". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. GCP Cloud Tasks provides no way to gather information on the body of requests that successfully completed.

(Which is a shame, because it seems quite natural. I just wrote an email to my own GCP account rep asking about this possible feature. If I get an update I'll put it here.)